# angularjs Disable textbox other while click on row

Tags: angularjs

I am using this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/q7x2iz8tnnEC2mnsvLAK?p=preview

it's working fine

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in Value" >
    <td>
        <span ng-show="!data.edit">{{data.question}}</span>
        <input ng-show="data.edit" type="text" ng-model="data.question" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="editUtterance(data)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="save(data)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Save</button></td>
</tr>
```

But my problem is If i click edit textbox enable that's fine if i click save then only that txtbox hided

How to disable that?

**angularjs Disable textbox other while click on another row textbox**

How to fix it this ?

[image]

Comment: This is poorly described. Do you just want to disable _Save_ buttons on other elements? Try this [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZKNv7LjeMsgJo9XGG7dL?p=preview)

Comment: i click question 1 edit button that time textbox enabled then i click question 2 edit button that time question 1 textbox should be disabled

Comment: Please edit your comment and all relevant code from the plunkr. Links expire eventually; when this happens it will decrease your question's value to other users having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the track of all buttons you have clicked and store them in a stack. Every time you edit a new input filed, you need to add the index of it to the stack. Once you save it (only the top one on the stack can be saved), you need to pop (remove) it from the stack (last element). This will jump to the next input field that needed to be edited. And so on, until your stack becomes empty.

```js
// Instantiate the app, the 'myApp' parameter must 
// match what is in ng-app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Value = [{
    id: 1,
    question: 'question 1',
    name: 'name 1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    question: 'question 2',
    name: 'name 2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    question: 'question 3',
    name: 'name 3'
  }]
  $scope.selected = []; // initialise the array / stack
  $scope.editUtterance = function(data, index) {
    //alert(data.id); 
    data.edit = true;
    //console.log(data.edit);
    $scope.selected.push(index); // add to the stack
  }
  $scope.save = function(data) {
    data.edit = false;
    if ($scope.selected) {
      $scope.selected.pop(); // remove last element from the stack
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <span ng-show="!edit">{{data.question}}</span>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>col 1</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in Value">
        <td>
          <span ng-show="!data.edit">{{data.question}}</span>
          <input ng-show="data.edit" ng-disabled="selected[selected.length-1] != $index" type="text" ng-model="data.question" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
        </td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-click="editUtterance(data,$index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button id="{{data.id}}" ng-disabled="selected[selected.length-1] != $index" ng-click="save(data)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit">Save</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Previously selected: {{selected}}

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```